# Ruby deploy to localhost using Capistrano issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capistrano

I am a beginner with Ruby and Rails, and I'm having an issue deploying my Rails app to my localhost.  The issue seems that there is some default config value somewhere, referencing example.com.

```
deploy@localhost:/home/user/code/project$ cap production deploy
DEBUG[8b34c0bb] Running /usr/bin/env [ -d ~/.rvm ] on 127.0.0.1
DEBUG[8b34c0bb] Command: [ -d ~/.rvm ]
DEBUG[b62cfdef] Running /usr/bin/env [ -d ~/.rvm ] on example.com
DEBUG[b62cfdef] Command: [ -d ~/.rvm ]
cap aborted!
```

It fails trying to deploy to example.com (obviously)

Where is this config value (file?) so I can get rid of it? I just deploy using Capistrano to localhost!

**EDIT config/deploy.rb**

```
set :application, 'project'
set :repo_url, 'git@github.com:excid3/myapp.git'

set :deploy_to, '/home/deploy/ninja'

set :linked_files, %w{config/database.yml}
set :linked_dirs, %w{bin log tmp/pids tmp/cache tmp/sockets vendor/bundle public/system}

namespace :deploy do

  desc 'Restart application'
  task :restart do
    on roles(:app), in: :sequence, wait: 5 do
      execute :touch, release_path.join('tmp/restart.txt')
    end
  end

  after :finishing, 'deploy:cleanup'
end
```

The :repo_url might be bogus.. not sure if that is affecting it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file is config/deploy.rb inside rails root folder. That is where the default configuration should be. It is usually something like

```
server "www.example.com", :app, :web, :db, :primary => true
```

Comment: Example.com is nowhere to be found.. please see my edit

Comment: Ahh, the elusive rails root folder.. how do you find that? I installed earlier and I dont really remember